# Getting Levels Right for Voice and Instrument on Videos

Tags: audio-recording, audio-interfaces, voice, instruments

I don't know if this is the right forum. Apologies if not.

I'm making videos on playing the recorder and I'm using a  good quality headset and a loop station (Boss rc505) as an audio interface. Trouble is the sound from the recorder is much louder than my voice, and even loads of compression on the audio interface doesn't make much difference (and also messes with the sound a bit too much). In principle I can try and remember to adjust the mic level every time I switch between talking and playing, but in practice I forget as often as not. I do have a condenser mic I could use instead of the headset, but I definitely need to listen as I play, as I'm often playing over a loop. The headset seems to make sense, but I keep making videos where my voice is just too quiet. Any suggestions for how best to address this issue please?

For an example of what I'm talking about, please see here:

Comment: You've got some pretty fierce veiling flare on the camera too;) All that 'haze' is caused by light from camera left shining onto the lens itself, then bouncing around inside the lens & camera body. If you can't change the lighting, you could probably shield the camera with just a black card, so its shadow falls on the lens without the card being in shot.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the flare issue. Another annoying thing is the "jumping" for example around 1:04. Do you know what could be causing that? Auto-focus or something maybe?

Comment: It could be some kind of autofocus confusion. I never use cameras on auto *anything* except for stills [mainly because they do irritating things like that & can never read my mind, so I set everything manually], so I'm not that familiar.

Answer (score 1):

Consider to mix your video in a proper multitrack video editor. Record your music to an audio workstation. Record it also to the video as you shoot your performance, but only to be used as a sync guide. Use in the rendered video soundtrack only what's mixed well together in the audio workstation.

It has been possible at least 10 years to import to a video editor a mixed music track and get it synced to the video which was shot by listening the same music track. The devices stay in sync so well for ex. 5 minutes or even more without any special syncing hardware. What's captured to the video can be low quality with no harm, if the stuff captured to the audio workstation is good.

Do not expect you can easily make plausible looking instrumental solos or vocal performances on the video by trying only to play or sing in sync with a prerecorded performance and by using only the prerecording as the video soundtrack. Extremely well trained persons can do it plausibly. 2...3 second quick clip may be successful easily, but not a longer passage. All long important solo parts must be performed and recorded to the audio workstation at the same time as the video is shot if the performance must look good.

If there's something so tricky that occasional errors must be fixed by re-recording you may meet a moment where the video and audio do not fit well enough. That can be covered by showing in the video something else.

**ADD** after reading again all given comments and other answers: The method above is nothing big nor complex. It only uses common tools available for everyone and gives a possibility to get something more finished than the linked video but without increasing the complexity substantially. BTW the video has quite good sound, but the skills of the performer are worth a finer production.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, it's not that bad. I could hear everything fine and my right ear is bad atm.
Recording two very different sources on one mic is always going to be troublesome, as you don't have isolated control. Also, I can hear a lot of muddy low end on your voice, which makes it less clear and  won't help when the compression is applied. But anyway, if you're not that into making it into a big, time-consuming production (as [@user287001 suggests](https://sound.stackexchange.com/a/51657/14770)), but you still want the dialogue to be a bit clearer, I'd just take some low end off the mic and then add some levelling compression in post to bring down the higher-level parts. You will probably have to mess with the parameters of the compressor a bit to get it right, but you can use those settings as a starting point for other similar videos.

That's a quick-fix method, and it's not ideal. If it was me, I'd use the condenser for the recorder and the headset mic for dialogue, record it all and just cut out the bits you don't want from each mic in post, providing you can record to different tracks. That would be a good balance of time and quality for me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You are right that ease is of the essence. I have a chronic health condition so if it's not quick n dirty, it's not going to happen at all. I don't even have a post process and would like to keep it that way if possible. On the rc505 loop station, there is master compression ranging from -20 to 20 (whatever measure it is - I don't know much about this kind of thing), and dynamic live compression as an input effect with the same range. I like your idea of "iterative improvement." I wonder if you could give an idea for the levels for these two fx as a staring point?

Comment: Hi Robin. The settings would really depend on the situation and the style of effect used on your device (i.e. what parameters you have to work with). If you have the time and the will, you should try to learn how to use `equalizers` and `dynamic range compressors`. They are both extremely useful, maybe the two _most useful_ effects in live audio. They really aren't that complicated to learn the basics, especially with the help of YouTube, but if your health limits you...  just talk louder ;) (we could also talk about this in [chat])